# Nesting composite-components in each other

Tags: jsf, facelets, composite-component

How can I nest composite-components in each other?

As an example, I have two composites representing the menu and the menu item which are used like:

```
<html ... xmlns:test="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/test">
...
<test:menu>
    <test:menuItem value="#{someBean.someValue}"/>
    <test:menuItem value="#{someBean.someOtherValue}"/>
</test:menu>
```

I would like to get it to render as:

```
<select>
    <option value="#{someBean.someValue}">#{someBean.someValue}</option>
    <option value="#{someBean.someOtherValue}">#{someBean.someOtherValue}</option>
</select>
```

The `menu.xhtml` is implemented as follows:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <select>
        <!-- How to get the <test:menuItem> here? -->
    </select>
</composite:implementation>
```

The `menuItem.xhtml` is implemented as follows:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <option value="#{cc.attrs.value}"> #{cc.attrs.value} </option>
</composite:implementation>
```

How do I get the `<test:menuItem>` in the place as identified by the comment in `<test:menu>` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [composite:insertChildren](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/insertChildren.html) tag like this:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <select>
        <composite:insertChildren/>
    </select>
</composite:implementation>
```